# "'[path]/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing" error

Tags: svn

I know by deleting the respective folder or a fresh checkout from the repository, followed by replacing the folder will solve the problem.

However, in my application the folder containing .svn will be deleted and and a new folder having the same name will be created. The newly created folder doesn't have the .svn folder.

When I try to commit, I get the error "`'[path]/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing`". Where `[path]` is the path in my application.

How do I force a check-in of this?

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is... why did the .svn folder disappear?

Comment: Why is your application folder containing /.svn deleted?

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar issue, and this worked for me:

```
svn rm --keep-local folder_name
svn add folder_name
```

This will remove the folder from version control, allowing you to keep your files in place. Then the normal `svn add` will add your *"new"* folder to version control.

-- EDIT --

Alternatively, use:

```
sudo rm --keep-local folder_name
svn add folder_name
```

This puts back my original answer as I disagree with the previous editor.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you get that error it means that the `.svn` directory either does not exist or doesn't not appear to be valid. Your best bet is to make sure it is deleted and then add the directory to the repository again:

```
svn add myfolder
```